# Why does she use こと at the end?

Tags: meaning, particle-こと

> 今は、依頼人を助けるための「情報」を聞き逃さないこと。

I understand the sentence but I don't know why she uses こと at the end.

[image: Ace Attorney]

Comment: Please don't try to answer questions in the comment section.